# Молитва перевод

Tags: значение-слов

Верою объем души моей и сердце тобою реченная

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите задачу, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: И текст пошире захватите, От точки до точки как минимум.

Comment: Странная молитва, однако! ;)

Comment: Прекрасная молитва православных христиан о даровании Благословения Божия. Произносится перед началом всякого дела. Так же и называется. Вот часть текста "от точки до точки": "Господи мой, Господи, верою объем в душе моей и сердце Тобою реченная, припадаю Твоей благости: помози мне, грешному, сие дело, мною начинаемое, о Тебе Самаем совершити, во имя Отца и Сына и Святаго Духа. Аминь."

Answer (score 2):

"Всё, что сказано Тобой, верой приняв в своё сердце и душу"

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/8257)

Comment: Является ответом на поставленный вопрос. Разъяснение значения приведённой строки.